# Запись в бд с динамической формы

Tags: javascript, php

имеется форма (вопрос, ответ (4шт), правильный ответ), при нажатии на кнопку добавить вопрос - добавляются такие же поля. Проблема заключается в следующем, как правильно организовать запись введённых данных с динамической формы? name имею сл вид ans1_1 (ans_1_2 - при создании 2 формы) и так далее.

```
</div>
до
<div class="mt-5 text-center">
<h4>Добавление вопросов</h4>
</div> <div class="questions">
<div class="question-items">
<div class="mt-4">
<label for="question_1" class="form-label"><b>Вoпрос #1</b></label> <input type="text" name="test_name" id="que_desc" class="form-control"> <div class="answers">
<div class="answer-items">
<div>
<label for="answer_text_1_1" class="form-label">Ответ #1</label> <input type="text" name="ans1_1" class="form-control">
</div> <div>
<label for="answer_text_1_1" class="form-label">Ответ #2</label> <input type="text" name="ans2_1" class="form-control">
</div> <div>
<label for="answer_text_1_1" class="form-label">Ответ #3</label> <input type="text" name="ans3_1" class="form-control">
</div> <div>
<label for="answer_text_1_1" class="form-label">Ответ #4</label> Binput type="text" name="ans4_1" class="form-control"[
</div> <div>
<label for="answer_text_1_1" class="form-label">Верный ответ (1-4) </label> <input type="text" name="true_ans_l" class="form-control">
</div>
</div> <hr>
</div> </div> </div> <div class="text-center mt-4">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addQuestion">Добавить вопрос</button>
Watch Sass Строка 109, столбец


AddTest.php JS app.js appjs > Gon(click') callback let resultNum = 1;
foot.php
до
$('.addQuestion').on('click', function() {
questionNum++; let questionBlock = $('.question-items');
questionBlock. appena <div class="answer-items"> <div>
<label for="answer_text_1_1" class="form-label"><b>Boпрос #S{questionNum}</b></label> <input type="text" name="que_desc_${questionNum}" id="answer_text_1_1" class="form-control">
</div>
<div>
<label for="answer_text_1_1" class="form-label">Ответ #${questionNum}</label> <input type="text" name="ansl_${questionNum}" id="answer_text_1_1" class="form-control">
</div> <div>
<label for="answer_text_1_l" class="form-label">Ответ #${questionNum}</label> <input type="text" name="ans2_${questionNum}" id="answer_text_1_1" class="form-control">
</div> <div>
<label for="answer_text_1_1" class="form-label">Ответ #${questionNum}</label> <input type="text" name="ans3_${questionNum}" id="answer_text_1_1" class="form-control">
</div> <div>
<label for="answer_text_1_1" class="form-label">Ответ #S{questionNum}</label> <input type="text" name="ans4_${questionNum}" id="answer_text_1_1" class="form-control">
</div> <div>
<label for="answer_text_1_1" class="form-label">Верный ответ (1-4) </label> <input type="text" name="true_ans_s{questionNum}" id="answer_text_1_1" class="form-control">
</div> </div> <hr>
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, если вам ответ в виде картинки напишут - норм?

Comment: Есть несколько путей. Например дайте элементам `input` имя а-ля `answer_text[]` тогда после `submit` Вам в переменную `$answer_text` придет массив со всеми значениями `input`. Либо генерируя динамически `input` (с помощью `javascript`) давайте им разные имена `answer_text_1_1`, `answer_text_1_2`, `answer_text_1_3` и тд. А после `submit` через конструкцию `$$` создавайте переменные с таким именем и получайте их значение.